# Problem sending value on form to echo the variable $visible

Tags: php, html

In the excersise the checkbox variable 0 or 1 should echo, however for some reason nothing is showing for 'Visble' when I try to echo it? The other parameters are echoing fine, just this one and I'm just not sure why.

the visible variable shows nothing echoing at all

checked commas and compared to code that did work however I cannot see any difference so can't see why it's not working

```
<?php 

require_once('../../../private/initialize.php'); 

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
redirect_to(url_for('/stafff/pages/index.php')); }

$id = $_GET['id']; $menu_name = ''; $position = ''; $visible = '';

   if (is_post_request()) {     $menu_name = $_POST ['menu_name'] ??
'';  $position = $_POST ['position'] ?? '';  $visibile = $_POST
['visible'] ?? '';    echo "Forms parameterffs <br />";  echo "Menu
name: " . $menu_name . "<br />";  echo "Position:" . $position .
"<br />";  echo "Visible:" . $visible . "<br />" ;    }  ?>

     <?php $page_title = 'Create page'; ?>     <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php'); ?>

<div id="content">

<a class="back-link" href="<?php echo
url_for('/staff/subjects/index.php'); ?>">&laquo; Back to List</a>

  <div class="subject edit"> 
    <h1> Edit Subject </h1>   

    <form action=" <?php echo url_for('/staff/pages/edit.php?id=' . h(u($id))); ?>" method="post" />
      <dl>
        <dt>Menu Name</dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="menu_name" value="<?php echo h(u($menu_name)); ?>" /></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>Position</dt>
        <dd>
          <select name="position">
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select>
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>Visible</dt>
        <dd>
          <input type="hidden" name="visible" value="0" />
          <input type="checkbox" name="visible" value ="1"<?php if($visible == "1") {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </dd>
      </dl> 

      <div id="operations">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Page"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_footer.php'); ?>
```

expect to see 1 in visible when I check the checkbox. At the moment no results are echoed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this code and see if this helps.
For some reasons, you have 2 inputs with the same name "visible" and this confuses the parsing logic.

```
<?php 

    require_once('../../../private/initialize.php'); 

    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
        redirect_to(url_for('/stafff/pages/index.php')); 
    }
    $id = $_GET['id']; $menu_name = ''; $position = ''; $visible = '';

    if (is_post_request()) {     
        $menu_name = $_POST ['menu_name'] ?? '';  
        $position = $_POST ['position'] ?? '';  
        $visibile = isset($_POST['visible']) ? $_POST['visible'] : '';    
        echo "Forms parameterffs <br />";  
        echo "Menu name: " . $menu_name . "<br />";  
        echo "Position:" . $position .    "<br />";  
        echo "Visible:" . $visible . "<br />" ;    
    }  
?>

<?php $page_title = 'Create page'; ?>     <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_header.php'); ?>

<div id="content">

<a class="back-link" href="<?php echo
url_for('/staff/subjects/index.php'); ?>">&laquo; Back to List</a>

  <div class="subject edit"> 
    <h1> Edit Subject </h1>   

    <form action=" <?php echo url_for('/staff/pages/edit.php?id=' . h(u($id))); ?>" method="post" />
      <dl>
        <dt>Menu Name</dt>
        <dd><input type="text" name="menu_name" value="<?php echo h(u($menu_name)); ?>" /></dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>Position</dt>
        <dd>
          <select name="position">
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select>
        </dd>
      </dl>
      <dl>
        <dt>Visible</dt>
        <dd>
          <input type="checkbox" name="visible" value ="1"<?php if($visible == "1") {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </dd>
      </dl> 

      <div id="operations">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Page"/>
      </div>
    </form>

    <?php include(SHARED_PATH . '/staff_footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: thanks, I used that instead but still nothing echo's through on visible when I click the check box

Comment: @AlgieSalmonFattahian Can you paste here the result of `print_r($_POST)`, this will help a lot.

Comment: when I type in // print_r ($_POST) I get the following so I can see that the result for $visible is showing in the background however I just can't seem to echo it.   Array ( [menu_name] => ljn [position] => 1 [visible] => 0 ) 1Forms parameter
Menu name: ljn
Position:1
Visible:

Comment: @AlgieSalmonFattahian I updated my answer, can you try again and tell me te result?

Comment: sure, I still don't get anything echoed on visible. I used print_r($_POST) and when I don't check the checkbox nothing happens, however when I do the value ones shows in the back ground. Forms parameterffs
Menu name: ljn
Position:1
Visible:
Array ( [menu_name] => ljn [position] => 1 [visible] => 1